# Multiple Ajax calls without disturbing others

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created Dynamic Tabs by using Jquery. In each tab, I have sent a ajax call and get some information and do some functions.

My problem is, If i create a First tab, the ajax call called and got informations and done some dunctions. Same as if i create second tab, that also work properly.

But If i create Second tab, when First tab ajax call or functions running, it stops the operation and second tab operations are started.

i want to create second tab dynamically, when the First tab functions Running(without stopping this)....simply like browser tabs loading....

How to do this please help me...

Comment: What have you tried? It should just work out of the box... if you post your code, we might be able to help you. Otherwise.... not so much.

Comment: Please post some code... no way to help you if we do not know what you are doing. Programming is an exact science.

Answer (score 1):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can do it easier

```
$.ajax("example.php", function(){
   //possible callback
});

$.ajax("example2.php", function(){
   //possible callback
});
```

this code triggers them both at the same time

Comment: exact same answer I posted two minutes before you, only with a weaker example and definitive url

Comment: @Drake: it's not the same. you've got only one ajax call, I do not send ajax request with object (like you do) and I haven't copied line of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are using standard XMLHTTPRequest object. Why cant you use some standardized javascript library like jquery / Mootools / Prototype / YUI  and more..

For a beginner jQuery would be quite fascinating. Try it out.

```
/*Call one*/
jQuery.ajax( 
    {
        url:"/theServerPage",
        data:{var1:a,var2:b, var3:2},
        type:"GET or POST",
        success:function(data, status){
            //data == server retured data
        },
        error:function(data, status){
            alert("Ooops..");
        }
    });


/*Call two*/

jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url:"/anotherServerPage",
        data:{var1:a,var2:b, var3:2},
        type:"GET or POST",
        success:function(data, status){
            //data == server retured data
        },
        error:function(data, status){
            alert("Ooops..");
        }
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't perform multiple calls to server

Comment: @NimChimpsky

Hi, my only intention was to tell how easy to make ajax call using jQuery apart from using standard XMLHTTPRequest object.

Answer (score -2):

I believe jquery doesn't have any issues with asynchronous Ajax calls

```
$.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
.success(function() { alert("success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It does not wait for the result before continuing execution in the current thread/function it is inside of. Thus multiple calls without disturbing others.

Comment: @Drake it does not perform multiple calls to the server, you are missing the point